# Django TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'required'

Tags: django, django-forms

it is probably too late again for me to find out what is wrong. I am having a simple form `forms.py`:

```
class ImportPortfolioForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(required=True)
    price_per_share = forms.BooleanField('Price per Share', required=False, initial=True,
                                   help_text="If not checked, total cost is expected in Price column.")
```

this is html:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="wide" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is `views.py`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImportPortfolioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        # work with file ...
else:
    form = ImportPortfolioForm()
```

I am getting error if I try to load form url:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'required'
```

If I remove required like this:

```
class ImportPortfolioForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(required=True)
    price_per_share = forms.BooleanField('Price per Share', initial=True,
                                         help_text="If not checked, total cost is expected in Price column.")
```

I can load form url. If I add file and send form, it claims field price per share is required: 
[image: image form upload]
I do not know why this behaviour happens. I guess request.POST in form initialization somehow adds `required=True` to the form. But I do not know why it does so or why I can not overwrite it in a form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
...
price_per_share = forms.BooleanField('Price per Share', required=False, initial=True)
```

Only model fields accept a label as the first positional argument. Form fields require you to use the `label` keyword. `required` is the [first argument](https://github.com/django/django/blob/14e6823d090a077d27f9f7caff2d505db31e55a7/django/forms/fields.py#L62) for form fields, so you're passing it both as a positional argument and as a keyword argument.

Generally you'd only use keyword arguments in form fields. The keyword you're probably looking for is `label`:

```
price_per_share = forms.BooleanField(label='Price per Share', required=False, initial=True)
```